# Capturing CancelKeyPress to stop an async console app at a safe point

Tags: c#, asynchronous, console, console-application, cancellation

I'm working on a small utility console app, built in C# 7.1 (which has `async Main` support).

The app takes one of several input commands and then starts a long-running process which iterates through tens of thousands of items, processing each.

I want to be able to cancel this process at any time (using CTRL+C), although the program should not immediately cancel but instead should finish the current iteration, then stop.

Here's a shortened version of what I have so far.

```
private static bool _cancel;    

private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                                      {
                                          eventArgs.Cancel = true;                                              _logger("Migration will be stopped after the current record has been completed.\n");
                                          _cancel = true;
                                      };

    while (!_cancel)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        // handle the various input commands
    }
}
```

Inside the methods which run the (optional) long-running process there is logic which checks for this global `_cancel` variable:

```
private static async Task RunPersonMigration(Order order)
{
    var nextPerson = // ...
    while (nextPerson.IsValid)
    {
        // business logic

        if (_cancel)
        {
            _logger("Person migration stopped by user.\n");
            return;
        }

        nextPerson = // ...
    }
}
```

However, whenever I hit CTRL+C the Visual Studio debugger asks me to locate an assembly, and it's usually a different assembly each time. For example, I've been asked to locate waithandle.cs and thread.cs. Because I'm unable to locate such files, the running debug process abruptly stops.

I can never see which line is causing the problem, and no amount of breakpoints helps.

Basically, I'm trying to use CTRL+C to exit a long-running process without exiting the console app.

Can anyone tell me how I should correctly handle cancelling a long-running console process at a point of my choosing?

UPDATE:
If I update my CancelKeyPress delegate...

```
Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                                  {
                                      **eventArgs.Cancel = true;**                                              _logger("Migration will be stopped after the current record has been completed.\n");
                                      _cancel = true;
                                  };
```

then this stops the program from crashing to a close, but I'd still like to be able to trap CTRL+C and use it as a means of exiting the long-running process *without* exiting the console app itself. Is this even possible?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Ctrl-C has special treatment in a console program, and that includes interrupting the process when you press the key, which the debugger is obliged to inform you of. VS does not _require_ that you find source files. You can simply continue executing the program at that point. You could even debug the assembly code without the source files. From your description, it sounds like there's nothing actually wrong. If you don't want the debugger to step in when the key is pressed, **don't run the program with the debugger attached!**

Comment: If I start a long-running process inside a console app, how can I allow the user to stop the process through a command instead of exiting the whole console? How do I pass in "Stop that process you're currently running"?

Comment: So what happens without debugger attached? Crash? Nothing (continues to execute)?

Comment: @Evk - Yes, it crashes - or immediately closes might be a better description.

Comment: Yes exactly what? :) Crash or nothing happens? If crash than with which exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177856/how-do-i-trap-ctrl-c-in-a-c-sharp-console-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203246/how-can-i-keep-a-console-open-until-cancelkeypress-event-is-fired

Comment: From your very vague description, it sounds like you are simply failing to set the `e.Cancel` property to `true` in the `CancelKeyPress` event handler. If you don't do that, Ctrl-C still terminates the program, even when you handle the event. See my proposed duplicates for more details.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Yes, you're right. I wasn't aware of `e.Cancel`. However, I still wish to keep the console app open after the process has been halted. I'm not sure this is even possible. I'll update the OP.

Comment: As I just wrote: if you set `e.Cancel`, your program should not be terminated. From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): _"By default, the Cancel property is false, which causes program execution to terminate when the event handler exits. Changing its property to true specifies that the application should continue to execute."_. It's amazing what you'll find, if you just look.

Comment: _"I still wish to keep the console app open after the process has been halted. I'm not sure this is even possible"_ -- if you set `e.Cancel` to `true`, the only thing left terminating your program **is your own code**. You've got a loop in your `Main()` method that runs until you set the `_cancel` flag and then your program exits. If you don't want your program to exit, **then don't exit**.

Comment: Yes, that's it all wrapped up now, thanks. The `while (!_cancel)` was something I dropped in as I was putting this post together, it had previously been `while (true)`, and putting it back to `true` now has the console app running exactly as I was hoping for. Thanks @PeterDuniho

Answer (score 14):

A working example using a `CancellationToken`, which can be passed down to lower levels:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource
        private static readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Application has started. Ctrl-C to end");

            Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cancel event triggered");
                cts.Cancel();
                eventArgs.Cancel = true;
            };

            await Worker(cts.Token);

            Console.WriteLine("Now shutting down");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }

        async static Task Worker(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested) // or optionally use cts.IsCancellationRequested field directly
            {
                // do work       
                Console.WriteLine("Worker is working");
                await Task.Delay(1000); // arbitrary delay
            }
        }

    }
}
```